# html5 pattern match float and/or percentage

Tags: regex, html, pattern-matching

I'm working with form validation and want to use pattern attribute for validate the input field. The field has the following criteria:

1. It must be a number (Integer or Float)
2. Can allow up to 2 decimal point (e.g.: 100.24)
3. Only one dot is allowed (e.g.: 100.25.35 is not valid)
4. May end with a percent(%) sign (But not always necessary)

So what should be the exact pattern `RegEx` for that. I'm trying with the following code but how to implement the percent condition?

```
<input type="text" 
       pattern="[0-9]+([\.][0-9]{0,2})?" 
       title="This must be a number with up to 2 decimal places and/or %">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are almost there. Add `%?` to your pattern:

```css
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"
       pattern="[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?%?"
       title="This must be a number with up to 2 decimal places and/or %">
```

Comment: Its not working taking more than 100% also as well as taking multiple %%%%%% like this

Comment: @abhay read the question again. Does not say it has to 100% or less. Only requirement is max 2 digits and an optional percent symbol. It is **not** accepting multiple %s.